# How to retain the state of a treeviewer in Java RCP application?

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp, treeviewer

I have a simple RCP application having couple of wizards out of which one is having a tree viewer. I want to retain the state of the selected item in the tree viewer next time I open that particular view. As of now I have implemented using **static variables** and its working fine.I want to know how it can be done in a better way?

//Sample Code

```java
private static RepositoryLocationItem lastRepoItemSelected;

Composite parent=new Composite(SWT.NONE)
treeViewer = new TreeViewer(parent);
treeViewer.setContentProvider(new MovingBoxContentProvider());
treeViewer.setLabelProvider(new MovingBoxLabelProvider());
treeViewer.setInput(getInitalInput());

treeViewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {

/* Setting the value of lastRepoItemSelected */
});


if(lastRepoItemSelected !=null)
{
treeViewer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(lastRepoItemSelected),true); 
}
```

Comment: Is this an e4 RCP or a 3.x compatible RCP (does your view extend `ViewPart`)?

Comment: No it doesn't extend from ViewPart.It  is basically a wizard page.

Comment: Then it is not a view, please use the correct terminology.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this is a 3.x style RCP (your view extends `ViewPart`) you can use the `saveState` method to save your view state:

```java
@Override
public void saveState(final IMemento memento)
{
  // TODO set values in the 'memento'
}
```

You can then use the `init` method to restore values from the memento when the view is shown again:

```java
@Override
public void init(final IViewSite site, final IMemento memento)
  throws PartInitException
{
  super.init(site, memento);

  // TODO restore from 'memento'
}
```

Note: Mementos are persisted across restarts of your RCP so you need to store values in them which are valid in a new instance of the RCP.

Also look at the [Eclipse wiki entry](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_does_a_view_persist_its_state_between_sessions%3F) for more information.

For a `WizardPage` you can use the `IDialogSettings`. You must set this up in your `Wizard` using something like:

```java
IDialogSettings pluginSettings = Activator.getDefault().getDialogSettings();
IDialogSettings wizardSettings = pluginSettings.getSection("id of your wizard");
if (wizardSettings == null) {
    wizardSettings= new DialogSettings("id of your wizard");
    pluginSettings.addSection(wizardSettings);
}
setDialogSettings(wizardSettings);
```

where `Activator` is your plugin activator class and "name of your wizard" is a id for your wizard (which can be anything as long as it is unique in your plugin).

In your wizard page you can then get the settings with:

```java
IDialogSettings settings = getDialogSettings();
```

`IDialogSettings` has lots of methods for saving and restore various sorts of values, such as:

```java
settings.put("key", "string value");

String value = settings.get("key");
```

Comment: ,In my real implementations it extends from Wizard not from the view.How it can be achieved?

Comment: In a Wizard you use `IDialogSettings` - added to answer

Comment: Thanks for the comment.It was helpful.I tried with IDialogSettings it  is working fine.But it is storing the values even after the session expires.I want something like static which only stores the value over the session and should flush the value once the session expires.

Comment: All the Eclipse mechanisms that I can think of are designed to go across sessions. I don't think there is anything better than statics for within a session.

Comment: Thanks for the support.Appreciated.